# Unable to run data-validator_2.11-0.12.1.jar on my local machine

Tags: scala, apache-spark, validation

I'm trying to use target data-validator, but when I run it in cmd, it shows me an error like:

```
D:\Spark\DemoTime>spark-submit --master local data-validator_2.11-0.12.1.jar --help
    21/12/28 15:05:41 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: No main class set in JAR; please specify one with --class.
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.error(SparkSubmit.scala:972)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:492)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:898)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1043)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1052)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

But if I give the main class name, it shows like:

```
D:\Spark\DemoTime>spark-submit --class com.target.data_validator.Main data-validator_2.11-0.13.0.jar --help
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/typesafe/scalalogging/Logger
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:42)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:955)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1043)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1052)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.typesafe.scalalogging.Logger
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 13 more
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I'm following the data-validator tool from target:
https://github.com/target/data-validator

But I'm unable to sort this thing out.

You can find the jar file at:
https://github.com/target/data-validator/releases

Hence I would request your help in running this tool.
Please let me know if you need anything else.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you read rhe README on GitHub? It contains the precise commands to run it..

Answer (score 0):

From the GitHub's README:

> Assemble fat jar: `sbt clean assembly`
>
> `spark-submit --master local data-validator-assembly-0.13.0.jar --help`

You need a *fat jar* of data-validator + its dependencies to be able to run it. You've only provided the data-validator simple jar.

Comment: Thanks Gaël, Yeah, I can see the difference.
The fat jar is around 26 MB, but the jar I used earlier is hardly 1 MB.
And running the --help command worked out.

Comment: You can upvote and accept the answer if it helped you ;)

Comment: I tried doing it, but stackoverflow shows something like this:
"Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: I had another issue with this data-validator...
If you wish you can have a look at this thread:
[running target data-validator results java.lang.IllegalArgumentException error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70507303/running-target-data-validator-from-target-results-java-lang-illegalargumentexcep)